# My Tor hidden service stops working and I must change the domain

Tags: tor

I run a Tor hidden service on a machine and I've properly configured the webserver, tor and everything else, following the official manual. However, once the site is up, after some minutes (about 30), it goes off (Tor browsers say that they were Unable to connect, after "Waiting for [domain].onion" for some time). I try restarting tor, restarting the server but nothing works. There is only a thing I can do to make it work again: deleting "hostname" and "private_key" files, so a new domain is generated and so everything will work like a charm again. For 30 minutes, again.

The server is untouched in this time. Nothing is changed on the server or network. No IP address changing, no settings modified. And no, it's not entering in stand-by mode, of course.

There is no error output on the console window, and I am not sure about other places/logs to look for error messages. I just have this on the console, but I don't know whether it's related to this problem or not:

```
[warn] Received http status code 404 ("Not found") from server (some domain:443) while fetching "/tor/keys/fp/[many hex chars]".
```